# Passing table pointer from C to Assembly Function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, assembly

I've got a problem which concern C and Assembly  cooperation. I would like to write a program which sending a table pointer to assembler's function, and in this function the table is filled of some data, next is returned to C and results are written to output.

The following code relate to C part:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern int oblicz(double,double, double, double, int, double *);//a signature of an  exter assembly function
int oblicz(double,double, double, double, int, double *);// the last position is a pointer  of my table
 //(some code)
 size =(int)k;
tab  = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*(size+1)); // alocation of memory
if (oblicz(a,b,P,Q,size,tab)) //the function
{
   for(i;i<size;i++)
    printf ("a result on %d index is %.10g \n",i, tab[i] );
}
```

Assembly part:

```
 %define a qword [ebp+8]
%define b qword [ebp+16]
%define P qword [ebp+24]
 %define Q qword [ebp+32]
 %define sizet dword [ebp+40]
 %define tab dword [ebp+44]// the table pointer
```

to make a code accomplishment simple I used below syntaxt in which Im setting only tab[0]

```
;i omited setting frame etc.
xor ebx,ebx
mov ebx, tab
mov qword [ebx], 4
```

and result in C is

```
a result on: 0 -is 1.669124542e-307 // it is always the same independently of value in this line : "mov qword [ebx], 4"
```

I would be gratful for any suggestion what may be wrong

Comment: Why not step through the code in a debugger ? That would show you exactly where the problem is quite quickly.

Comment: As it is always the same value, you're not writing to the correct memory location, and you provided not enough information, e.g. arch, assembler, function calling standard, ... The code to set up the stack frame would also be helpful. And +1 to 'step through using a debugger'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are moving the literal **integer** 4 to the first element of tab.  The first element will look like this:

```
04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
^^ low address       ^^ high address
```

In [IEEE 754 double precision numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), the exponent is in the top bits and in your case is zero.  As the fraction is non zero (4 in your case), you have a [subnormal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number).  This means that you have written a very small number and not 4.

I'm guessing you want to move the **double** version of 4 to that address.

Comment: Thank you I finally  understood what was my mistake. I found also solution based on your idea. and this is the answer on question how to repair it:

First simple declaration:

     segment .data
      Four dw 4

next

    mov ebx, tab
 
    fild word [Four]  //conversion int-> 
    mov ebx, tab      
     fstp qword [ebx] // pop from stack streight to tab

Mayby it's  a little crappy but it's works.
Thanks also for avices of using gdb ;). It's really usefull!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you I finally  understood what was my mistake. I found also solution based on your idea. and this is the answer on question how to repair it:

First simple declaration:

```
 segment .data
  Four dw 4
```

next

```
mov ebx, tab

fild word [Four]  //conversion int-> 
mov ebx, tab      
 fstp qword [ebx] // pop from stack streight to tab
```

Maybe it's  a little crappy but it works.
Thanks also for avices of using gdb ;). It's really usefull.!